# Why can't i make toggle effects. and jquery doesn't register a class change

Tags: jquery, function, events, toggle

I have been trying to make a toggle for alot of things in jquery now, i am still fairly new to jquery.
I have tried toggleing a class, copying off of other scripts. And also the normal toggle function.

```
$(function(){
    $('div').toggle(function(){
        $(this).text('odd clicks');
    }, function(){
        $(this).text('even clicks');
    });
});
```

https://www.jsfiddle.net/bVr2r/84

Here is an example. Can someone explain to me why my selected content gets a fade out?

also here is a an example of my idea with a class swap:

http://www.jsfiddle.net/bVr2r/85

i know it is not perfect, was made in a rush, but point still stands.
Anyone knows why 1 of those don't work? or have another idea that would make it work?
i have tried alot of different threads and i just cant seem to get a toggle effect.

last example.
i tried to make a next button, simply by changing the class when i click. Firebug shows that the class gets changed, but it seems like jquery doesn't realize that the new class is existant. Its the same problem but different example

Comment: add four spaces to the start of your lines of code, to get it to format correctly. If you don't, links to jsfiddle don't work, so we can't actually see the links you thought you added.

Answer (score 0):

Switching the version of jQuery to pre-1.9 will make it work.

It is documented with the rest of the upgrade guide at http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#toggle-function-function-removed

Comment: Thanks for the answers, it works now in 1.8
but that still doesn't explain all the problems i have had with adding and removing a class.
f.eks. a NEXT/PREV button change, so a click #nxt1 removes nxt1 and adds nxt2. Then clicking #nxt2 will remove nxt2 and add nxt3. and so on.

Anybody got an answer for that? :)

Comment: Sorry, I totally ignored that second half. I would recommend changing it to something like this: http://jsbin.com/ivemuj/1/edit Before it was still registering the click event on the object that HAD class "hello" even after the class was removed. The event was still bound to that object, despite the class swap.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use the .toggle() event which was deprecated as of jQuery 1.8 and removed in 1.9 (http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/). Plus you're trying to use it with jQuery 2 which is still in beta. Either use a different version of jQuery pre 1.8 that supports toggle(). or bind your mouse clicks with .on() and count the clicks and fire your functions accordingly.

Comment: It was removed entirely in 1.9.

Comment: interesting with the count of clicks, since i am still new to jquery and javascript, i will try to create a counter, but if someone beats me to it i would be greatful